# SQL Query: looking for null

Tags: sql

The question is: You want to be the first to book and pick seats for a flight. Find the `flight_num` and date of all flights for which there are no reservations.

From the following tables:

- `Flights` (`flight_num, source_city, dest_city`)
- `Departures` (`flight_num, date, plane_type`)
- `Passengers` (`passenger_id, passenger_name, passenger_address`)
- `Bookings` (`passenger_id, flight_num, date, seat_number`)

My answer was:

```
SELECT D.flight_num, D.date
FROM DEPARTURES D, BOOKINGS B
WHERE B.passenger_id = NULL
```

I know this is wrong, but can anyone tell me why? What is the answer to this?

Comment: Among other things, you want `is null` to check for null values.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged. Right now, without **any** join condition, you basically get a **cartesian product** - each row in `Departures` combined with each row in `Bookings` - most likely **not** what you need!

Comment: Have you learned this in a course or from a book? If so, time to upgrade or get your money back. I think those old style joins were invented by the Romans.

Comment: Furthermore you are cross joining now. You will need to state which fields are related to which in order to properly join the tables. `WHERE d.flight_num = b.flightnum` for instance

Comment: See [this explanation of joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Answer (score 1):

This might be better:

```
SELECT D.flight_num, D.date
FROM DEPARTURES D JOIN BOOKINGS B ON D.flight_num = B.flight_num 
WHERE B.passenger_id IS NULL
```

I'm not sure if it would be possible to book, but not reserve a seat number. If it is, then you need to change the WHERE clause for that.

Answer (score 0):

This might work?

```
    SELECT D.flight_num, D.date
    FROM Departures D LEFT OUTER JOIN Bookings B
    WHERE B.passenger_id IS NULL
```